# Porque não consigo passar um parâmetro para a classe?

Tags: python, classes, python-3.x, parâmetros

Estou tentando passar o parâmetro "tinta" para a classe "Caneta" mas não consigo. Já tentei usar expressões booleanas ao invés do index, mas mesmo assim sem resultado. Alguém poderia me dar um *help*?

```
class Caneta():

    açao = 'escrever'

    def __init__(self, tinta):
        self.tinta = tinta

    def NivelTinta(tinta):
        rng = range(0,100)

        for tinta in rng:
            if tinta in rng[5:100]:
                print('A caneta está boa')
                break
            elif tinta in rng[1:4]:
                print('A caneta está falhando')
                break
            else:
                print('A tinta acabou')
                break

CanetaAzul = Caneta(50)

CanetaAzul.NivelTinta()
```

Toda vez que eu executo o código aparece "A tinta acabou", sendo que deveria aparecer "A caneta está boa", pois o parâmetro que coloquei é "50".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta um pouco de lógica no seu código, além de ter um certo erro.

Primeiramente, você não está recebendo **`tinta`** como parâmetro, e isso nem é necessário uma vez que o valor já está salvo no objeto. Você está recebendo **`self`** como parâmetro (que é o objeto propriamente dito). Então, ao invés de tentar acessar diretamente **`tinta`**, é necessário acessar a propriedade (ou atributo) **`tinta`** que está dentro do parâmetro (também chamado **`tinta`**, neste caso - eu mudei o nome pra **`self`** justamente pra evitar a confusão).

Segundo, este *loop* é completamente desnecessário. Você não precisa fazer um *loop* pra descobrir se o nível de tinta está num determinado intervalo, só precisa usar os comparadores lógicos **`<`** (menor que) e **`>`** (maior que).

Outra coisa importante, mesmo que o *loop* fosse necessário, a instrução **`break`** faz com o código "pule pra fora do *loop*", isso quer dizer que a condições serão avaliadas apenas uma vez e depois disso o *loop* é parado.

Fiz uma adaptação no seu código e agora ele está funcional.

```
class Caneta():

    acao = 'escrever'

    def __init__(self, tinta):
        self.tinta = tinta

    def NivelTinta(self):
        print(self.tinta)

        if(1 <= self.tinta <= 5):
            print('A caneta esta falhando')
        elif(5 < self.tinta <= 100):
            print('A caneta esta boa')
        else:
            print('A tinta acabou')

CanetaAzul = Caneta(50)
CanetaAzul.NivelTinta()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito! Quando eu estava tentando o código com expressões booleanas essa era uma das coisas que estava tentando fazer: concatenar dois operadores booleanos, só que eu estava usando o "and", então não estava dando muito certo. Essa sua explicação do "self" esclareceu muita coisa também :)

Comment: Show! Sempre bom ajudar. Você pode sim usar o `and`, mas não teria porque, já que o Python (`♥`) dá essa facilitada pra nós. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so].

Comment: Obrigado! Só uma coisa: Me ocorreu uma dúvida agora de porque tenho que igualar "self.tinta" e "tinta" no método __init__. Já que no método "NivelTinta" utilizei "self.tinta" e não "tinta".

Comment: Acontece que no método `init` você recebe o **valor** tinta e atribui ("injeta") ele como valor do parâmetro dentro de `self` (que é o objeto `caneta`). Ali você pode usar qualquer nome, faça um teste e mude o nome do parâmetro para `t`. E mude a segunda linha para `self.tinta = t`, o comportamento continuará igual. No segundo método você está usando o valor `tinta` que existe dentro do objeto, a variável usada no `init` já não existe mais. 
E mais um detalhe, você está **atribuindo** `tinta` para `self.tinta` e não **igualando**.

Comment: Acho que entendi, então a função dessa **atribuição** é porque os parâmetros do método init esperam um valor para o mesmo poder "funcionar" (digamos assim). :)